# Rust bincode enum binary serialisation

Tags: serialization, enums, rust, bincode

I'm fairly new to Rust and am using bincode in my project.  The encoding of enum variants is an issue that I've been trying to deal with as I am interfacing with an existing server.  The old project was written in C and the compilier option of "fshort-enums" was defined.

In the old C project I would define an enum something like:

```c
enum test_enum {
    Start,
    Init,
    Complete,
}
```

and then when this data was put into the packet it would take up 1 byte like this:

```
0x00,
0x01,
0x02
```

If I defined the enum as:

```c
enum test_enum {
    Start,
    Init,
    Complete = 65535,
}
```

then when this data was put into the packet every variant would take up 2 bytes like this:

```
0x00 0x00,
0x01 0x00,
0x02 0x00
```

Now I've found a way to configure `bincode` enum encoding to change from the default 4 bytes to be the appropriate size for the value like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum TestEnum {
    Start,
    Init,
    Complete = 65535,
}

let x = TestEnum::Complete;
if let Ok(bytes) = bincode::options().with_varint_encoding().serialize(&x) {
    println!("{:?}", bytes); // [2]
}
```

Question1: How do I force `bincode` to make all variants take up 2 bytes?

Question2: How do I force `bincode` to apply the enum variant value?  (in this example `TestEnum::Complete` has a value of 2 instead of 65535).

Comment: the point of bincode is to handle this for you, you can't config these

Answer (score 3):

`Options::with_varint_encoding` is probably not what you want, since it will only use 1 byte for integers that are less than 256. You can use `Options::with_fixint_encoding` to encode integers with the same precision as their Rust type, but you don't need to specify it, as it is the default already.

Serde is structural; it doesn't really care about how the data is actually represented in memory. The numerical values you assigned to the enum are lost and `bincode` will only see the names of the variants.

You can solve this by configuring `serde` to convert your enum into an integer before exposing it to the `bincode` serializer:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Clone)]
#[serde(into = "u16")]
enum TestEnum {
    Start,
    Init,
    Complete = 65535,
}

impl From<TestEnum> for u16 {
    fn from(value: TestEnum) -> u16 {
        value as u16
    }
}
```

Then your code gives the expected result:

```
let x = TestEnum::Complete;
if let Ok(bytes) = bincode::serialize(&x) {
    println!("{:?}", bytes); // [255, 255]
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the helpful response.  I've just tried this and it works exactly as I need.  Much appreciated!

Comment: How would I implement this for an enum with values like `#[repr(u8)] enum Checksum { Crc16([u8; 16]), Crc32([u8; 32])  }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I did use the answer provided by @Peter Hall but I had to add an implementation for all of the enums that are defined (there are lots of them) to be able to serialise them and a second implementation to be able to deserialise.  So I continued my investigation and found an alternative that seems a little more useable to me.  Instead of adding an implementation for each enum, I'm now using the [num_enum](https://crates.io/crates/num_enum) crate from crates.io and adding some attributes to the enums.  So the code looks like below:

```
use num_enum::{IntoPrimitive, TryFromPrimitive};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Clone)]
#[serde(into = "u16", try_from = "u16")]
#[repr(u16)]
enum TestEnum {
    Start,
    Init,
    Complete = 65535,
}
```

I just thought this might help others in the future.